# Android: How to pass Activity from MainActivity to a separate non-Activity class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am writing an Android application in which I am accessing a shared resource, implemented through extending the Application class to a public class (shared resource). Below is the code containing my shared resource (**ScheduleStorage.java**):

```
import android.app.Application;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScheduleStorage extends Application {
    private Map<String, Match> schedule = new HashMap<String, Match>();

    // Getter
    public Map<String, Match> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    // Setter
    public void setSchedule(Map<String, Match> newSchedule) {
        this.schedule = newSchedule;
    }
}
```

The following line of code accesses the schedule property of `ScheduleStorage`:

```
fun getSchedule(): Map<String, Match> {
    return (getApplication() as ScheduleStorage).schedule
}
```

As you can see, in order to access the ScheduleStorage resource, I need to get the application first. However, when I am passing the Context into another class, when I execute the following line of code:

```
ScheduleStorage scheduleStorage = context.getApplication().getSchedule();
```

> Cannot resolve method getApplication()

How do I get the Activity in a non-Activity class?

Comment: what are non-activity class?

Comment: @UuuUuu It's just a class that isn't MainActivity

Comment: it depend on where you pass context to. It's fragment, broadcast receive or something else

Comment: @UuuUuu I am trying to pass the Context to a class that extends LinearLayout (represents a custom component)

Comment: If you control that other class, why not pass it with the type of `Activity` instead of `Context` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast view's context to activity which the view is running in

```
((Activity's name which pass to constructor of view) 
getContext()).getApplication().getSchedule();
```